# List of events in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have 3 Controls - ContractSelection, ContractInfo and ContractClips

I have an additional class - ContractStructureService.  This contains a property - SelectedContract

The contract selection control displays a list of contracts to the user in a combo box

When the user selects a contract, the SelectedContract on the service is changed.

I know how to do all that - the tricky bit is that I want both ContractInfo and ContractClips to be told when the selected contract has been changed

```
public class FlexContractStructureService : IFlexContractStructureService
{

    #region IFlexContractStructureService Members

    private Contract _selectedContract;

    public ViewModels.Contract SelectedContract
    {
        get { return _selectedContract; }
        set
        {
            _selectedContract = value;
            OnSelectedContractChanged(new SelectedContractChangedEventArgs(SelectedContract));
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler SelectedContractChanged;

    protected virtual  void OnSelectedContractChanged(SelectedContractChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedContractChanged != null)
        {
            SelectedContractChanged(this, e);
        }

    }
```

How do I do this with Silverlight?

I would assume that if I have code in both ContractInfo and ContractClipInfo like

```
service.SelectedContractChanged += ContractChanged
```

Wouldn't this mean that when I call OnSelectedContract changed, only 1 object is notified?

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several questions rolled into one here.

For the last part, an `event` is meant to be multicast, ie to be able to notify a list of delegates. So, no, not only 1 object notified.

Now, for the main question, in Silverlight, you have several options, depending on what you're already using:

- You can use events and delegates as you propose, if you can get direct references to the relevant objects. This causes a coupling that might not be desirable, and also, poses a leak/delegate spam risk. What this mean is: you have to be very careful to unsubscribe each delegate that was added to an event.
- You can use a non-coupling communication pattern, for instance a `Messenger` (MVVM Light), or something similar (broadcaster/subscribers). You have a point of broadcast here: `OnSelectedContractChanged` where you can send a notification (in MVVM Light again: `Messenger.Default.Send(new SelectedContractChangedNotification(_selectedContract));`). This notification can be received wherever you need elsewhere in your application (`Messenger.Default.Register<SelectedContractChangedNotification>(this, OnSelectedContractChanged);`) with as many receivers as you need.